What's the difference between 'a large amount' and 'large amounts'?
I've come across the following sentence 'Large amounts of aluminium have only been produced for around 100 years..' and it got me thinking whether it is OK to substitute it for 'a large amount' and what shade of meaning it will have then.

(singular) a single amount, a large amount. In the singular, amount refers to helping, portion, quantity of product e.g. "He poured himself a generous amount of maple syrup" In the case of aluminium, "a large amount" would suggest it was produced in a unique area of the world whereas several amounts, and large amounts [note the absence of indefinite article "a"] refer to the quantity of aluminium produced worldwide.

OP has asked about two sentences


Large amounts of aluminium have only been produced for around 100 years.
A large amount of aluminium has only been produced for around 100 years


I. Explanation: "large amounts of" and "a large amount of" with an example.
Let's consider another example and explanation:
The archaeologist found large amounts of gold. OR.
The archaeologist found a large amount of gold
If the gold was found in only one location, then use the singular. If it was in several locations, then use the plural.
II. History of Aluminium.
Let's consider what OP's sentence implies:

Reference Wikipedia:.
World production of the metal grew from 6,800 metric tons in 1900 to 2,810,000 metric tons in 1954, when aluminium became the most produced non-ferrous metal, surpassing copper.
In the second half of the 20th century, aluminium gained usage in transportation and packaging. World production continued to rise, reaching 58,500,000 metric tons in 2015. Aluminium production exceeds those of all other non-ferrous metals combined.
(Rise in production from 1900 to 2015 :
Initial production (1900): 6,800 metric tons.
Final production (2015): 58,500,000 metric tons.
Rise in production:
58,500,000 - 6,800 = 58,493,200 metric tons.
Percentage increase:
(58,493,200 / 6,800) * 100% ≈ 860,488%
Or approximately:
860.49 times or 86,048.8% growth)

When describing quantities across multiple locations, use:
"Amounts" (plural).
Since aluminium is produced in different locations throughout the world, "amounts" appropriately reflects:

A number of production sites
Distinct geographic locations

On the other hand, use "Amount (singular)" if speaking of a single place or a single number. -

The mine contains a large amount of aluminium.
A large amount of aluminium is processed every day in the facility.

Therefore "large amounts of" is appropriate in the given example and cannot be replaced by "a large amount of".

Shouldn't it be 'A large amount of aluminium haS only been produced for around 100 years..'?

@Yukatan You are right. I edited my answer.

The mine contains a large amount of aluminium.= The mine contains large amounts of aluminium. It's like: He has lots of money. OR He has a lot of money.

In terms of production of this non-ferrous metal:
large amounts in this context means that some thing occurs more than once.
large amounts of aluminium: the production of more than a single batch.
a large amount of aluminium: refers to a single batch OR could refer to an overall amount produced at some location.
Only context will tell.
[The British spell it: aluminium]

The Australians, New Zealanders, South Africans, and Irish spell it that way too. The Canadians used to, but don't any more.

Scientists are more familiar with the metal and call it "Al".

@TimR How is that even relevant here?
